# How to calculate mAP0.5:0.95 in YOLOv4 using darknet?

Tags: object-detection, yolo, yolov4

I am using YOLOv4 with darknet in Google Colab. Everything works fine. Unfortunally, I can only get the mAP evaluation for IoU=0.5 using

```
!./darknet detector map $_path_to_objdata_file $_path_to_configuration_file $_path_to_weights
```

How can I calculate mAP for another IoU? Or mAP@IoU0.5:0.95?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, i managed to find a way using the flag -iou_thresh XXX:

```
!./darknet detector map $_path_to_objdata_file $_path_to_configuration_file $_path_to_weights -iou_thresh 0.95
```